# How to polish a metal flooring like the one in this image?

Tags: cleaning

What equipment/chemical is needed to clean my metal flooring.

[image]

Comment: The instructions and materials to clean this surface can be found or asked on our [Home Improvement site](http://diy.stackexchange.com); unfortunately, this type of *how-to* is off topic for Lifehacks.

Comment: Is there a way to migrate a post  to a different site then?

Comment: It is better to simply repost the question in the context of the site itself.